# SQL - Order by column where two records have the same value in a column

Tags: sql

If I have data like this, ordered by points:

| Name | DoB | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ben | 11/01/1990 | 2000 |
| Tom | 21/01/1980 | 1000 |
| Sam | 02/01/2001 | 500 |
| John | 01/01/2000 | 500 |

Here, I would like to rank the people in the table so their points are in order, but if two people have the same points, the person who is older will appear first, so in this case Sam should be last, and John should be second last. Any ideas how I do this?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I think I fixed it: SELECT MatchID, Name, DoB, Tournament, Year, r.Ranking,r.Points
FROM Matches m
JOIN Ranking r
 ON m.Position = r.Ranking
WHERE Year <= 2019 AND YEAR >= 2017
ORDER BY Year, r.Points, DoB DESC

Comment: A descending sort on dob would result in the youngest appearing first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just something like that?

```
select *
from table
order by Points desc, cast(DoB as DATE) asc
```